# Merge rows together who have the same value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, tensorflow

I have a CSV file like this (which parsed by using the pandas by using read_csv):

```
Filename f1 f2 f3
1.jpg     1 0.2 0.3
1.jpg     0 0.8 0.7       
2.jpg     1 0.3  0.2
```

How would I use this dataset and change it into a numpy array which will look like this:

```
[
   [[1,0.2,0.3],[0,0.8.0.7]],
   [[1,0.3,0.2]]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create nested lists by [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with lambda function, [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) is for avoid convert column `Filename` to lists:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)

L = (df.set_index('Filename')
       .groupby('Filename')
       .apply(lambda x: x.to_numpy().tolist())
       .tolist())
print (L)
```

Or:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=0)

L = (df.groupby('Filename')
       .apply(lambda x: x.to_numpy().tolist())
       .tolist())
print (L)

[
 [[1.0, 0.2, 0.3], [0.0, 0.8, 0.7]], 
 [[1.0, 0.3, 0.2]]
]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but this unfortunately does not help due to the fact that the I would like to have all answers for 1.jpg inside of an numpy array. So if I run a line of code similar to arr[1] it will output [[1,0.2,0.3],[0,0.8.0.7]]

Comment: @jr123456jr987654321 - Sorry, I missed it, answer was changed