# Merging several rows together and making turning into an numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, tensorflow

I have got a parsed .csv file (I have done this by using pd.read_file).
This is the csv file:

```
Id A B C
1  7 6 5
1  4 3 2
2  1 0 0
```

Is it possible to make turn that into this (in a numpy array):

```
[
[[7,6,5],[4,3,2]],
[[1,0,0],[0,0,0]]
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert pandas dataframe to NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array)

Comment: @Ananda - I think not, because not added `[0,0,0]`

Comment: Adding to jezrael's point, unfortunately not, but I found an answer though which answers the 1st part of my question. But not the part turning of adding the [0,0,0] until it is a matrix with a even shape. Here is the answer that answers the 1st part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65840573/merge-rows-together-who-have-the-same-value-in-a-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add missing rows by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`Series.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.stack.html) and then convert to nested lists:

```
L = (df.set_index(['Id', df.groupby('Id').cumcount()])
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .stack()
        .groupby('Id')
        .apply(lambda x: x.to_numpy().tolist())
        .tolist()
        )
print (L)
[[[7, 6, 5], [4, 3, 2]], [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]
```